# Error deleting memberUid from a large LDAP group

Tags: ldap, openldap

I have an group with ~40,000 members. I'm trying to deleted a `memberUid` from it.

This is my changeset:

```
dn: uid=foobar,ou=People,dc=example,dc=com
changetype: delete

dn: cn=foobar,ou=Group,dc=example,dc=com
changetype: delete

dn: cn=giantgroup,ou=Group,dc=example,dc=com
changetype: modify
delete: memberUid
memberUid: foobar
```

This is my invocation:

```
ldapmodify -c -x -w 'password' -D cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com -f delete.ldif
```

This is the output (once I've already run it several times, so the user and the user's group are already deleted):

```
deleting entry "uid=foobar,ou=People,dc=example,dc=com"
ldap_delete: No such object (32)
    matched DN: ou=People,dc=example,dc=com

deleting entry "cn=foobar,ou=Group,dc=example,dc=com"
ldap_delete: No such object (32)
    matched DN: ou=Group,dc=example,dc=com

modifying entry "cn=giantgroup,ou=Group,dc=example,dc=com"
ldap_modify: Other (e.g., implementation specific) error (80)
```

How do I debug `ldap_modify: Other (e.g., implementation specific) error (80)`? This is a very active LDAP server, so enabling server debug output is overwhelming and I'm not sure what to grep for.

Update: Error in the slapd log:

```
5afb42f3 bdb(dc=example,dc=com): Lock table is out of available lock entries
5afb42f3 => bdb_idl_insert_key: c_get failed: Cannot allocate memory (12)
5afb42f3 conn=1005 op=3: attribute "memberUid" index add failure
```

More diagnostics [from this blog post](https://blog.janestreet.com/openldap-dbd-and-you/):

```
# db_stat -h /var/lib/ldap/ -c | grep "Maximum number of locks"
1500    Maximum number of locks possible
1511    Maximum number of locks at any one time
14  Maximum number of locks in any one bucket
422 Maximum number of locks stolen by for an empty partition
48  Maximum number of locks stolen for any one partition
```

Based on this, what would a good value for `set_lk_max_locks` be? 40000? And is there a recommended way to change this value for a running OpenLDAP server?

I've moved the follow-up question here: [How do I change the maximum number of locks for OpenLDAP bdb?](https://serverfault.com/questions/912528/how-do-i-change-the-maximum-number-of-locks-for-openldap-bdb)

Comment: With `olcLogLevel: stats` I think you should be able to see enough of the connection to find out what's going on, though you may also need `olcLogLevel: stats2`. You can grep for either your bind if that's an infrequently used dn, or for `err=80`, which shouldn't be occurring regularly. From there you can get the connection number (`conn=`) and see more details of the specific operations.

Comment: perhaps the LDIF is a bit corrupted with linespaces or something, try a dos2unix on it, you need to ensure that you have a newline after each line.

Comment: @84104 Thanks! I've identified the underlying error.